# about setting up rust-playground

Tags: init-file, rust

I have a problem with setting up rust-playground on Emacs.
I installed rust-playground on Emacs 25.0.93 of Macbook Pro.
When I run rust-playground, the following error happens.

[image]

```
rustc /Users/hirokinoguchi/.emacs.d/rust-playground/at-2017-05-16-150310/snippet.rs -o snippet && 
/Users/hirokinoguchi/.emacs.d/rust-playground/at-2017-05-16-150310/snippet

/bin/bash: rustc: command not found

Compilation exited abnormally with code 127 at Tue May 16 15:03:12
```

I can run rustc command on bash on Emacs.

[image]

Maybe I need to set up rustc's PATH in a elisp file.

Could you give me some advice?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Take a look at [`exec-path-from-shell`](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell).

Comment: You can customize variable `M-x` `customize-variable` `rust-playground-bin`. By default it has value _rustc_ for your case just set it as _/usr/local/bin/rustc_. But more right way described in the answer below, you should use PATH in Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you've got it in your shell, it looks as though you've not got `/usr/local/bin` in the PATH environment variable for your Emacs.  You could verify this by doing `M-x getenv` PATH. There might be a better way, but I use a little bit of code like the following in my Emacs init file:

```
(defun add-to-path (dir)
 "Add DIR to PATH environment variable and Emacs' `exec-path' list."
  (setenv "PATH" (concat dir ":" (getenv "PATH")))
  (push dir exec-path))

(add-to-path "/usr/local/bin")
```

This adds paths to both the environment so that they'll be inherited by external processes run by Emacs, and to ensure that Emacs can find binaries in these directories.

Comment: I wrote the code above in the init.el, but I face with with same error.

Comment: Have you evaluated the new code or restarted your Emacs? What  value does M-x getenv give for PATH?

Comment: Thank you for your advice! When I M-x getenv, "/usr/local/bin/rustc:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9:" appears

Comment: Ah, it's "/usr/local/bin" (without the rustc) that you need to add to the path. The PATH environment variable specifies a list of directories in which the shell will look for programmes to run.

Comment: Could you tell me how to fix "/usr/local/bin/rustc:" to "/usr/local/bin/"?

Comment: Change the add-to-path call in your init file to `(add-to-path "/usr/local/bin")` and then either restart Emacs, or put the cursor anywhere between the parenthesis and use `C-M-x` to run the `eval-defun` command.

Comment: Now I added "/usr/local/bin" to Emacs' PATH.  And I checked the PATH with getenv command.  But I cannot solve the issue...  I guess there is something wrong with the elisp package.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the package -  I just installed it and worked perfectly for me.  Has anything you've done here changed the problem as you see it at all?  If it has, exactly what is the problem that you see now?